# Openlayers initial extent

Tags: javascript, openlayers

According to the OpenLayers documentation, the constructor, OpenLayers.Map(), allows for an additional property *extent* which is *"The initial extent of the map"* ([see here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Map)).

However, I cannot get it to have any effect. I know I can set an initial extent by calling *.zoomToExtent()* **after** constructing the map. But I would like to use this *extent* property because I set a *zoomend* event in the *eventListeners* property but don't want it to trigger with an initial call to *.zoomToExtent()*. Does anyone have a clue how to use this *extent* property?

This is the code that isn't working

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
        extent: bounds,
        layers: [osmLayer,vectorLayer],
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        eventListeners: {
            zoomend: function() {
                //..zoomend event listener code
            }
        }
    });
```

In the above example:

- *bounds* is a valid *OpenLayers.Bounds* object
- *osmLayer* and *vectorLayer* are valid *OpenLayers.Layer* objects of which *osmLayer* is the base layer.

What happens with above code is that the map is completely zoomed out (in fact you can't actually see anything) and any attempts to pan results in errors being thrown. To get to map into a correct state the user has to zoom in and then panning works again and you can see the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not sure off-handedly how to make the code you listed work, however the following alternative has worked for me:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")});

//ADD A BUNCH OF LAYERS AND SUCH HERE

//Set map center to this location at this zoom level
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-93.9196,45.7326),5);
```

As a last resort, you could put a line at the beginning of your zoom function:

```
if(!map_ready) return;
```

And then set the variable `map_ready` to true at the appropriate time.

Comment: The *map_ready* flag is a good idea. For the meantime I've resorted to something similar to your solution by calling zoomToExtent() and then only attaching the eventListener after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

The "extent" option mentioned in the documentation [is there probably by mistake](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/commit/e8af06e6ae805bee7cf3acacca869fddb96dd561). It does not exist. I checked the source code and could not see any code handling such option. I contacted the author and he already created a [pull request](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/1046) for the removal of this option from the documentation.